# Is there any way to have a customizable class element in html that a css file can extract custom values from?

Tags: html, css

For example, say I want to create text in HTML with the color blue and a size of 13px.

Is there any way I can do something like:

```
<h1 class = "blue 13px">Hallo</h1>
```

And then use CSS to make it blue and 13 px without doing:

```
.blue 13px {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using CSS classes, you could use inline styling in your HTML elements:

```
<h1 style="color: blue; font-size: 13px;">Hallo</h1>
```

Because of its poor maintenance and reuse qualities, this styling strategy is generally not advisable though. Use with caution. ;)

Also note that the CSS code that you provide in your question is invalid. CSS class names have to be valid [CSS identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). This would be more correct:

```html
<h1 class="blue-13px">Hallo</h1>
```

```css
.blue-13px {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

And also note that you can include CSS rules inside your HTML page as well (without using a separate CSS file):

```html
<style>
    .blue-13px {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>
<h1 class="blue-13px">Hallo</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS

```
:root
{
 --css_h1_color: rgba(204,204,204,.2);
}

h1 {color: var(--css_h1_color);}
```

## JavaScript

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--css_h1_color');
```